# Issues Building Flutter App on macOS 14: Command CodeSign Failed

Tags: flutter, xcode

Everytime I try and build my flutter app since updating to macOS 14 I get the following message.
`> [ +100 ms] Failed to build iOS app

> [   +6 ms] Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
>
> [   +8 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
> Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
> [  +18 ms] "flutter run" took 95,168ms.
> [  +15 ms]
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:760:9)
>
> #2      FlutterCommand.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1297:27)
>
> #3      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
>
> #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:339:9)
>
> #6      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:285:5)
>
> #8      run.. (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:115:9)
>
> #9      AppContext.run. (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
>
> [ +264 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 252ms
> Running 1 shutdown hook
> [  +10 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
> exiting with code 1
>
> flutter doctor:
>
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
> Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
> Chrome - develop for the web
> Android Studio (version 2022.3)
> VS Code (version 1.83.1)
> VS Code (version 1.83.1)
> Connected device (3 available)
> Network resources`

Creating and running a new blank app (it runs successfully through Xcode but fails in VSCode).
Locking and unlocking keychain access.
Removing all extended attributes in my project.
Reinstalling VSCode.
Running flutter clean.

is there anyway to identify whats causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was moving project dir to a folder which is not synchronized with iCloud. Try it! :)

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/136131